# What's with the whole window thing? Why am I bothering with windows?

Tags: windows

I am looking at building an addition for a study and one issue is the need for windows. Frankly, I don't need to look out a window at a tree when I am working in my study and much of my work is at night, so the whole "natural light" thing is irrelevant.

Windows add a lot of expense and heat loss to the building, so why do people even build windows? So they can look at the ugly bushes or the blind alley or the siding of the house next to them? Let's face facts: most windows do not look out on beautiful ocean vistas, or the Grand Tetons, so why even bother with them?

Comment: What would be your escape plan in case of a fire at the doorway/nearest room?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean There are doors on either end of the addition. What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Sometimes code requires them, and most people like windows. If you don't, then don't add them; it's your project. I don't know what else we can tell you here...

Comment: What @dandavis said.

Comment: Before electric light, we used to NEED windows, and they were designed to allow natural light into the right areas of a house. For example, the kitchen and work areas on the south side, the bedroom on the east, etc. Now it seems houses are orientated whichever way looks best from the street, sun be damned, so the functionality of windows is indeed diminished from the past, before AC, central heat, and electric lights.

Comment: You could save a lot of money just living in a shipping container with an electric blanket and a water cooler.

Comment: @batsplatsterson That sounds like a good idea, except that it would not match the architecture of the main house.

Answer (score 5):

Let's approach from a different direction: increase of value to your house.

Any realtor or homeowner will tell you that certain things add value to your home, and others do not.  Even for things that add value, you will only expect to recoup "most" of the cost (since you are doing it for yourself and will only sell to someone else eventually).  For evidence, google the phrase "recouping cost of home improvement", and note that a well-done kitchen remodel of 20k will add maybe 16k to the value of your home.  A well-done addition or remodel is one which 'improves mass appeal' of your house, because then it's easier to sell and more people bid on it.

With all that in mind, I say:
skipping the window does offer short-term savings of a few grand or so,
but adding the window is an investment that makes your whole house worth more.

Answer (score 4):

Windowless rooms tend to be less appealing to most people for a variety of reasons. Homo Sapiens evolved with psychological and biological connections to daylight. Most of us gravitate to it, and it can affect our moods.

Fresh air can have a similar effect, refreshing and invigorating us. Even if you're consciously unaware of these effects, they're present in most people.

As for your heat loss claim... windows allow solar gain as well. If properly positioned with respect to the sun and summer shade trees, they can cut heating costs.

And if your bushes (and the wild creatures they attract) are ugly, you may need new bushes. Or a change of attitude. Mr. Sparrow doesn't approve of your current one.

[image]

<sub>Photo credit me

https://www.audubon.org/field-guide/bird/white-crowned-sparrow</sub>

Comment: Well, Mr. Sparrow isn't paying my oil bill.

Comment: He smiles his birdy smile, knowing that a modern window has at least half the r-value of the wall (more in older homes), and that its small area has very little impact on your heating bill, making the benefits well worth it.

Comment: What I read is that windows are easily 20% of the heating/AC cost in a small standalone building (like the addition I have planned). Also, each window adds over $5,000 to the cost of construction.

Comment: Neither of those numbers seem reasonable to me.

Comment: Oh, really, how's this for reasonable: for a high end "architectural" window with the argon-triple pane nonsense in the Boston area the quote is over $15,000 ... per window.

Comment: What quote? What are we talking about here? Are you shopping "high end" windows? I'd surmise $1-2,000 with a reasonable builder for a basic window. Half that if you're building yourself. As for heating cost, low single digits for a single window in your addition. It sounds like you've made up your mind, though, and are actively seeking corroborating evidence. I don't have much else to add.

Comment: Also not all windows loose the same energy, properly installed Low-E windows don’t loose like 1950’s single pane.

Answer (score 2):

If your “Study” has a bed or couch in it, it’s classified as a “sleeping room” and will need an egress window, unless your entry door opens directly to the exterior. (See ICC R311)

If so, you’ll need a smoke detector too.

You’re getting a Building Permit, right?